# How to execute a loop only once

Tags: python, loops

I'm creating a program that provides the user with job offers. For example they're given 10 offers and they decide to reject the first 3 right off the bat. From there I'm taking the maximum number out of the three and I want to accept the next best offer. Although my program is accepting the best offer instead of the next best.

To explain a little further, let's say offer 4 was higher than the max number out of the first 3, I want that offer to be considered 'accepted' even if offer number 5 is higher. Here is my code at the moment, the problem lies that the last 'if' statement keeps repeating causing it to give me the best offer instead of next best.

```
    offerRejList = []
    offerList = []
    counter = 1
    counterRej = 1
    while counter <= jobOff:
        offer = random.gauss(65, 5)
        offerList.append(offer)
        if counterRej <= jobRej:
            offerRejList.append(offer)
        print('Offer #' ,counter, ': $',offer,'-',)

        counterRej += 1
        counter += 1
        if offer > max(offerRejList):
            acceptedOffer = offer
```

Comment: Did they teach you how to use `break`?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm

That's all you need. Immediately after you have "acceptedOffer"

Comment: Thank you that's a good solution, although I do have to keep producing the rest of the offers. I have to show them a statistic at the end showing them on how much money they potentially missed out on.